# Angular Material Drag Drop within Component Module

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material2, angular-components, angular-module

I'm trying to use Angular's CdkDropList and CdkDrag behind a custom component module and have the sort work. I've posted a [stackblitz example here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xw6sf6) with two examples. The first example uses my custom module. The second demonstrates the same code but without a custom module. Both examples to not use arrays to build the CdkDrag areas as shown in the [Angular Material Docs Here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples). I would like to know how to get 'Example 1' working to support drag drop reordering using my custom components and without arrays to build the drag list. Below is the basic component setups. Please refer to the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xw6sf6) for full code example.

Components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dragPanel',
  styleUrls: ['drag.component.scss'], // reference not important
  template: `
    <div cdkDrag class="example-box">
         <b>{{ title }}</b>
         <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class DragComponent {
  @Input() title;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dragListPanel',
  styleUrls: ['drag.component.scss'], // reference not important
  template: `
  <div #cdkList cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div> 
  `,
})
export class DragListComponent {
  @ContentChildren(DragComponent) dragPanels: QueryList<DragComponent>
  // @ViewChild(CdkDropList) cdklist: CdkDropList;

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // Debugging
    this.dragPanels.forEach(panelInstance => {
      console.log(panelInstance);
    })
  }
}
```

Module:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop'; 

// Custom components
import { DragComponent, DragListComponent } from './drag.component';
const components = [
  DragComponent,
  DragListComponent,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, DragDropModule],
  declarations: components,
  exports: components,
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
export class UiDragpanelModule {}
```

To use the above example within your app.component.html page etc.

```
   <dragListPanel>
     <dragPanel title="One">data 1</dragPanel>
     <dragPanel title="Two">data 2</dragPanel>
     <dragPanel title="Three">data 3</dragPanel>
   </dragListPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an issue of the `CdkDropListContainer` not being a direct parent of the drag element. Someone can correct me if I am wrong, but I believe the `ng-content` containers are the reason for this not working, as they are a boundary.

> More information about this issue below... there are provided
>   workarounds with a stackblitz for your review... this issue is still open, so allowing out of scope binding may still be in the works.

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/14099

---

`CdkDrag` accepts a reference to the `CdkDropList`, you may be able to pass a reference in.

> `dropContainer: CdkDropList`   **Droppable container that the draggable is
>   a part of.**

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag

Comment: @Marshall Thanks for the reply, there is certainly an open issue around 'CdkDropListContainer' as shown https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/14099 although I'm still unable to get the workaround by dddeeennn  shown here https://stackblitz.com/github/dddeeennn/angular-material-drag-column-header to work correctly. It appears this also uses arrays to build the headers in the example. Could you expand your answer by providing a working example as suggested without arrays?